# How to check if two lists have the same element in the SAME position

Tags: python, list

I want to check if two lists have the same letter in the same position, and if so increase a "score" variable by 1. For example:

```
list1 = [a, b, f, d]
list2 = [a, b, c, d]
```

So the score here should be 3 since only a, b and d (index 0, 1 and 3) match in both list1 and list2

Comment: The same letter in a specific position, or in _any_ position?

Comment: Are lists always the same length? what have you done so far?

Comment: @Sayse Yes they are always the same length

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through both lists using list indexing:

```
for i in range(len(list1):
    if list1[i] == list2[i]:
        score += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1=['a','b','c','d','e']
l2=['a','c','b','d','e']
k=[True for i in l1 if l1.index(i)==l2.index(i)]
cnt = len(k)
print("Count of letters having same index in both the lists is " ,cnt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply zip and sum using generator expression:

```
sum(first == second for (first, second) in zip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ord` and `count`:

`print([ord(list1[i]) - ord(list2[i]) for i in range(len(list1))].count(0))`

[ord](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#ord)
[count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)